# How to suppress URLs in PIP install log?

Tags: python, docker, pip

Is there a way to suppress the URLs in the PIP installation log?
Currently it looks like this:

```sh
pip install -r requirements.txt
...
 Collecting docker==4.3.0
#12 24.22   Downloading https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/COMPANY/_packaging/TOKEN/pypi/download/docker/4.3/docker-4.3.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl (145 kB)
```

As you can see, this exposes the private access key or CI token in the log (e.g. in a Docker build).

Adding the Flag `--quiet` would suppress this output, but I would like to keep these lines:

```sh
 Collecting docker==4.3.0
```

Is there a way to suppress only the URLs?

Answer (score 4):

The message `Downloading URL` is implemented [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/7ec0fa5142466f8402bb866a1dcfb8ca6ffdc66b/src/pip/_internal/network/download.py#L52) as

```py
logger.info("Downloading %s", logged_url)
```

so to hide it, one could set the logging above the `INFO` level (like to only show `WARNING` and above).

Interestingly, pip does seem to try to redact private information from the url with

```py
logged_url = redact_auth_from_url(url)
```

The source is [here](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/7ec0fa5142466f8402bb866a1dcfb8ca6ffdc66b/src/pip/_internal/network/download.py#L44).

Comment: At least the source of the problem is found. There is an [issue](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/9746) regarding this too.